# Previous and Next Buttons and Search with Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having a weird issue with my [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/):

**Step 0** - Data table loads and includes next and previous buttons

**Step 1** - Execute a search with enabled DataTables search box

**Step 2** - Leave focus of search box or remove all characters

After step 2, the previous and next buttons disappear, yet they were there in Step 0.

Perhaps I left out a property someplace? I have no idea what is causing this.

Thanks much,

```
  $("#tblResults").dataTable({
       "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
        "bSort": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "bFilter": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "@Index.NoData",
            "sInfo": "@Index.Showing _START_ @Index.To _END_ @Index.Of _TOTAL_.",
            "sInfoEmpty": " ",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "@Index.Next",
                "sPrevious": "@Index.Previous"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
       { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [4,5,6,7,8,9,10] }
        ],
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        if (oSettings._iDisplayLength > oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {
            $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
        }
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding an else block inside the fnDrawCallback:

```
if (oSettings._iDisplayLength > oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) 
    $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
else 
    $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').show();
```